Cannot use 'changeTheme' from PrimeReact Context
I am trying to use the changeTheme functionality as documented here on prime reacts website here
I have setup a very basic online sandbox here
    //CSS
    import "./App.css";
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    import { PrimeReactContext } from "primereact/api";
    import LoginPage from "./components/Loginpage";

    //Prime React styles
    import "primeflex/primeflex.css";
    import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";
    import "primereact/resources/primereact.min.css";
    import "primeicons/primeicons.css";

    function App() {
        const {changeTheme} = useContext(PrimeReactContext);
          return (
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
                </Routes>
              </Router>
           </div>
        );
    }

    export default App;

The line
   const {changeTheme} = useContext(PrimeReactContext);
Throws the error
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'changeTheme' of 'useContext(...)' as it is undefined.
I have tried reaching out to the authors on their discord as well as searching here and elsewhere online.

You are not using PrimeFaces.

You can fix this issues by adding PrimeReactProvider in index.jsx
index.jsx
import { PrimeReactProvider } from "primereact/api";
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <PrimeReactProvider>
      <App />
    </PrimeReactProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
);



Note: useContext() call in a component is not affected by providers returned from the same component. The corresponding <Context.Provider> needs to be above the component doing the useContext() call.
Reference: https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext
Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/solitary-leaf-forked-7qnjdj
